# How to prevent external script from top level navigation

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, sandbox

On our site, external scripts from ad provider (all Javascript) occasionally navigate the user to some malware site.

Any JS-code can be loaded from the ad provider (e.g. sometimes it creates an iframe to display the ad, sometime the ad is displayed directly in the main page).

I wonder how to safely **prevent any external script from triggering top level navigation**, whether the script is executed from within an iframe or not.

Current solution is to add [CSP sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox) header in every response:

```
header( 'Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-downloads allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-top-navigation-to-custom-protocols;' );
```

The strategy is to prevent top level navigation *by omitting the `sandbox allow-top-navigation` header*.

Is this a sufficient solution in order to prevent top level navigation? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to php.  Please could you remove the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient because in your case you also need third party scripts running at the top level. Omitting `allow-top-navigation` only prevents iframes from changing the URL of your page (the top). i.e. links such as:

```html
<a target="_top" href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
```

```js
open('https://example.com', '_top')
```

Here’s a demo of the above anchor on an iframe and on the top level context:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/1_Qo74q8SxQ

**How to protect against it?**

You’ll need a known-good version of the 3rd party assets, and load them with a [`nonce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce). That will ensure that other versions won’t run in your page.

Comment: Thanks. Then I wonder what's the use of header `sandbox allow-top-navigation` if omitting it has no effect.

Comment: In this reference https://content-security-policy.com/sandbox/ there is nothing said that CSP `sandbox` is only applied to iframes. To me it seems that omitting `sandbox allow-top-navigation` prevents top level navigation from any script if it's run from within an iframe or not.

Comment: @Abid I added a video demo. It's `allow-top-navigation` that’s for iframes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Eric Fortis's answer here but I would also like to say that if your ads are redirecting to malware sites, then the solution is to get a different ad provider that doesn't sponsor malware, such as Google AdSense.
Not only are you supporting malware developers with the ad provider you're using, you're also going to lose repeat business because of the affected visitors.  Additionally, most shady auto-links like that also cheat the legitimate sites that are paying for click-thru by forcing a click.

You can force shut-off redirects in the browser settings.  In Chrome, simply enable safe browsing.  Shady activities such as these will eventually be auto-blocked by the browsers, but for now it's a setting.

Comment: Thanks. Then please show me a way how to get the AdSense approval ;-) we tried it a dozen times with no success ...

Comment: google isn't the only one but if you aren't getting approval, I suggest you find out why and then fix the problem.  Google loves money so they will have a valid reason to say no.